# Binding ViewModel command to another window view?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a `ListBox` that is in my `UserControl` which is displayed on my main window. My ViewModel for the main window contains two ICommands, remove and add from listbox. I have successfully bounded my remove command to the listbox from the main window. However, I have a separate window that opens from the main window which includes a button to add a `ListBoxItem` to the listbox. My main window ViewModel does not exist in the context of the second window. I can not instantiate another ViewModel as it will not contain the items that already exist in my ObservableCollection found in the ViewModel.

How can I go about solving this in an MVVM way? Should I Create another ViewModel for the second window View? If so, how can I ensure all my pre-existing ListBoxItems are visible to it?

**Update:** As requested, minimal code.

My UserControl containing my ListBox:

```
<UserControl>  
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel>
            <ListBox x:Name="lstBox" ItemsSource="{Binding myList}" DisplayMemberPath="Desc">
            </ListBox>
            <Button x:Name="btn_Remove" Content="Remove" Command="{Binding RemoveCommand}" 
                    CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=lstBox, Path=SelectedIndex}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

My MainWindow ViewModel containing the ICommands:

```
  public class MainWindowViewModel {

      private RelayCommand removeCommand;
      private RelayCommand addCommand;

      public ObservableCollection<myObjModel> MyList {
          get;
          set;
      }

      public void createList() {
          ObservableCollection<myObjModel> myList = new ObservableCollection<myObjModel>();
          myList.Add(new myObjModel { Desc = "test" });
          MyList = myList;
      }

      public ICommand RemoveCommand {
          get {
              if (removeCommand == null) {
                  removeCommand = new RelayCommand(param => remove((int)param));
              }
              return removeCommand;
          }
      }

      public void remove(int i) {
          MyList.RemoveAt(i);
      }

      public ICommand AddCommand {
          get {
              if (addCommand == null) {
                  addCommand = new RelayCommand(param => add((string)param));
              }
              return addCommand;
          }
      }

      public void add(string desc) {
          Telegrams.Add(new TelegramyObjModelmModel { Desc = desc });
      }
 }
```

My MainWindow XAML:

```
<Window
xmlns:uc="clr-namespace:myClass">
    <Grid>
        <uc:UserControl x:Name="myUserControl" Loaded="myUserControl_Loaded"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Followed by the code behind

```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window {

    MainWindowViewModel ViewModelObject;

           public MainWindow() {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

            private void myUsereControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
            ViewModelObject = new MainWindowViewModel();
            ViewModelObject.createList();
            myUsereControl_Loaded.DataContext = ViewModelObject;
        }
      }
```

Comment: Hi there, welcome to StackOverflow.
Please don't forget to add a working example or a code sample to help other users help you find a solution to your question!

Comment: What is the `DataContext` of the second `Window`, i.e. what ViewModel is behind it? Is it in some way linked to the ViewModel of the first `Window`? Is it instantiated by that ViewModel? I would imagine you'll need some kind of reference passing into it.